# "How is that like for you?" in Russian

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

So the kind of situations I am thinking is in these kinds of contexts:
"How was that like for you to give a presentation in front of your class?"
"How is that like for you to be a parent?"
"How was that like for you to stand in line for so long?"

Or simply in a dialogue:

> **A:** Yesterday I saw my parents.

> **B:** How was that like for you?

Some things I thought of are:

"Как это было для тебя?"
But I think it sounds weird and I believe one doesn't say such things in Russian.

"Что ты чувствовал...[when this or that happened]?"
or
"Как ты себя чувствовал?...[when this or that happened]?"
Is "what/how did you feel". But "how was that like for you" feels more general, is not only about feelings, and gives more freedom to the person answering.

EDIT: some more explanations about "how is that like for you":

Maybe another wording for "how was that like for you" is "how was your experience". Basically one is asking in a open way mainly about the internal experience of the person: what happened for you, how it happened for you, what did you feel, what did you think, what did you experience, etc. Meaning one wants to hear everything or anything about that event/situation, but more centered about the internal experience, felt sense, inner world of the person, rather than the external circumstances. Here I use the word "experience" as in "испытывать, чувствовать, переживать"

Comment: can you please clarify for Russian speakers what exactly mean "how is that like for you" ? I mean of course we can guess and you already provide some information - but still it would be nice to clarify.

Comment: Sure, I added some more clarifications of my understanding of that question in English. Please let me know if more clarifications would be helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Consider following example:

> **A:** Вчера я повидался с моими родителями.

> **Б:** Ну и как [тебе / вы в итоге поговорили / ты себя по этому чувствуешь / всё прошло / всё было]?

Exactly like in English the phrase "how is that like for you?" actually, depending on actual event and context, has many meaning, "ну и как?" can mean a lot of things. It also can be followed with some clarification as well.

You can also use "ну и чего?" or "и как ты" etc. - there's a lot of combinations and, again, exactly like in English I doubt one can list them all.

You are also right that "Как это было для тебя?" sounds very unnatural, but one can say something like `ну и каково тебе было?`.

Comment: + "И как оно?"...

Answer (score 0):

> "How was that like for you to give a presentation in front of your class?"

"Как прошла презентация?" - literally "How the presentation passed?" - the only correct way you asks. It also asks for "feelings" if you make a correct intonation, not just asking on the run.

> How is that like for you to be a parent?

"Как тебе отцовство?"

> How was that like for you to stand in line for so long?

If there is a negative aspect of standing in the line and you also think the same way, then you may ask:

"Как тебе очередь?" - literally "What do you think about that queue?"

Or you may make a joke - "Ну что? Постоял? =)" (So, what? Have you finished standing? =)